# .NET Different References List for Debug / Release

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In my debug build I have a reference to a DLL that is only required in the Debug configuration (the reference is for CodeSite, a logging tool).

Is it possible to exclude this reference in the Release build (my logging class only uses this reference when built in the Debug configuration).

Using VB.NET and VS2008.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is possible but it will require you to manually edit the .vbproj file.  Once you have the file open you'll an XML reference tag for the DLL's you've referenced and it will look like the following

```
<Reference Include="SomeDllName" />
```

You need to add a condition property which species it should only be done during debug time

```
<Reference Include="SomeDllName" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" />
```

Comment: Ooh, that's nice - I didn't realise you could add a condition on a single reference.

Comment: @Jon, I think you can do it on pretty much any entry in a MSBuild file.

Comment: Thank you, exactly as required.  Thanks also Jon.

Comment: +1: Thanks a million, this is a really neat feature, and I wonder why it is not accessible through the GUI...

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to do this, but you'll need to mess with the project file manually.

We do this in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) so we can have a .NET 2.0 build and a .NET 3.5 build. For instance:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Release 2.0' ">
  <Reference Include="System.Core">
    <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    <Aliases>global</Aliases>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
    <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

That should be enough to get you started :) Basically take the current reference out of where it is in your normal project file, and put it in its own ItemGroup with an appropriate condition.